# Dynamic Countdown Timer

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a program that uses countdown timers, it works but I am trying to do something new with this blender timer.  It uses a NumericUpDown and is supposed to add 5 minutes for each value, 1 being 5 minutes and 2 being 10 minutes etc.  I did find a way adding 5 minutes to BlenderCountDownFrom but when pressing the BlenderButton to stop it, it kept the new value.  I am a complete novice and don't know what I am doing so the code is probably horrible!  The actual countdown code I got from an example on the internet.

BlenderButton is both the start and stop for the countdown.  It will use a "Set" button to program the amount of minutes from the NumericUpDown.

```
Dim BlenderCountDownFrom As New TimeSpan(0, 5, 1)

Dim BlenderStopwatch As New Stopwatch

 Private Sub BlenderButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BlenderButton.Click
        If BlenderButton.Text = "Start" Then
            BlenderTimer.Interval = 100
            BlenderButton.Text = "Stop"
            BlenderTimer.Start()
            BlenderStopwatch.Reset()
            BlenderStopwatch.Start()
        Else
            BlenderButton.Text = "Start"
            My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
            BlenderTimerLabel.BackColor = Color.White
            BlenderTimer.Stop()
            BlenderStopwatch.Stop()

            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:05:00")
            Me.MiscTab.Text = "Misc"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BlenderTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BlenderTimer.Tick
        If BlenderStopwatch.Elapsed <= BlenderCountDownFrom Then
            Dim toGo As TimeSpan = BlenderCountDownFrom - BlenderStopwatch.Elapsed
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", toGo.Hours, toGo.Minutes, toGo.Seconds)
        Else
            BlenderTimer.Stop()
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Alarm.Blender, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
            Me.MiscTab.Text = "Alarm"
            BlenderStopwatch.Stop()
            BlenderTimerLabel.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BlenderSetButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BlenderSetButton.Click
        If BlenderUpDown.Value = 1 Then
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:05:00")
        End If

        If BlenderUpDown.Value = 2 Then
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:10:00")
            'This below doesn't work             
            Dim BlenderCountDownFrom As New TimeSpan(0, 10, 1)
        End If

        If BlenderUpDown.Value = 3 Then
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:15:00")
        End If

        If BlenderUpDown.Value = 4 Then
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:20:00")
        End If

        If BlenderUpDown.Value = 5 Then
            BlenderTimerLabel.Text = ("00:25:00")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  That Blender class is problematic because it's not clear where that JBCountdown reference is coming from.

Comment: Yeah sorry, JBCountdown is the main form.  Public Class Blender is a module, I may not use the Blender module, probably best to keep it all in the JBCountdown form.